# Javascript error addFiles() is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

So when I click my addFiles button I get an error in firebug that says

> "TypeError: addFiles is not a function."

This doesn't make any sense to me because if I go into firebug and look at the script the addFiles() function is there.  My code looks like:

```
<input id="addFiles" type="button" name="addFiles" value="Add Files" onClick="addFiles();">

<script type="text/javascript">
function addFiles()
{

}

</script>
```

edit:

```
<form id="eventForm" onsubmit="eventInfo();">
  <table id="hornEvent" class="horntable">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="text-align:right">
        <input id="addFiles" type="button" name="addFiles" value="Add Files" onClick="addFiles();">
        <input id="close" type="submit" name="close" value="Close">                     
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There must be something else, that code should work fine. Any other js error on the console?

Comment: can you see another errors on your page?

Comment: In this code there is no error..............I think you have not posted complete code............

Comment: open this fiddle in FF and see that it works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/JedQu/1/

Comment: I added in some more code to get a better understanding of whats going on.  My eventInfo(); function works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your function to function somethingElse() and see if it works. It may be a conflict with the name of the function/input (same name/id addFiles)

Comment: This was the problem, I changed the name and everything worked.  Thanks!